# Can I reset a quest in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm on the *Diplomatic Immunity* quest and I'm playing on an Xbox. I never received my weapons out of the chest and I've tried loading from old saves which still did not take me out of the Thalmor Embassy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your answer: There is no way to restart missions; not even on PC. All you can do is use console commands to complete the mission, but that's for PC and you're using an Xbox 360. Just get on with the game

Comment: Thank you but how do I get on with the game I have no weapons..

Comment: @NaomiBoenrer Go buy some new ones.

Comment: I CANT, NO ONE WILL LET ME LEAVE THERES ENEMIES EVERYWEAR

Comment: @NaomiBoenrer pickpocket? use magic? fist fight??

Comment: @NaomiBoenrer where does your character stand as of now? If you're outside, run for the quest marker. Have you gotten to the kitchen with the distraction? Did you put anything with Delphine's friend back in solitude?

Comment: I'm past the kitchen, I'm where u have to get your stuff out of the chest and then he locks the door, but my stuff was never in their so I've been trying to leave that position for sma couple weeks now because I simply can't leave the embassy

Comment: Go find a good place to hide, then start planning your escape. It is possible to escape without as much trouble, but is very hard. What are your primary skills at and what perks do you have on them?

Comment: Turn down the game difficulty and you can kill everyone with your fists.

Comment: @Nelson clever. You are right, just turn it down and punch everyone like its street fighter

Comment: This is one mission where you can get really stuck if you didn't prep your equipment properly.  I can't tell you how many times I went in there without any lockpicks.  One time I gave all my main gear to the inside-man and a dragon attacked me on the way to the carriage...

Comment: That happened to me too. I got in the carriage and couldn't get out or progress until the dragon died. It died, but that was like 15 mins later. Oh and on one of my first runs, I didn't put lockpick or potions with mr.slave guy